# Compiling Crypto++ for armhf for cross compiling

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, cross-compiling, crypto++

I want to cross compile the library crypto++ for deployment on a beaglebone running Debian. My host PC runs Ubuntu 14.04 LTS in a 64-bit configuration.

I face the following problem when I invoke the make command from eclipse

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++-4.8 -L/usr/include/cryptopp -o "GCMwithAES"  ./main.o   -lcryptopp
/usr/lib/../lib/libcryptopp.so: file not recognized: File format not recognized
```

My guess is that since the compiler is configured for armhf, it cannot recognize the library that was compiled for amd64.

I have successfully cross compiled and run standard (ie no external libraries) programs from my host PC to my target device.

Solutions that I have tried

- Used libcrypto++ packages with the architecture specified as `armhf` as done in multiarch. The armhf libraries get installed ( as per apt) but I am unable to include and link my code with them.
- Manually try to compile the library as per the instruction given on this [wiki](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Linux). However, I always run into errors whenever I try to compile the library.

How do I install the libcryptopp libraries of the armhf architecture on my x64 based PC so I can cross compile? or is there any other way to resolve this issue.

**Edit**

As suggested in the answer below I tried out the method suggested. I slightly modified the script `setenv-embed.sh` since I had `gcc-4.8` instead of `gcc-4.7`. The results of running the script are

```
CPP: /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-cpp 
CXX: /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
AR: /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-ar
LD: /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld
RANLIB: /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-ranlib-4.8

ARM_EMBEDDED_TOOLCHAIN: /usr/bin
ARM_EMBEDDED_CXX_HEADERS: /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/4.8.2
ARM_EMBEDDED_FLAGS: -march=armv7-a mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=neon -I/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/4.8.2 -I/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/4.8.2/arm-linux-gnueabihf 
ARM_EMBEDDED_SYSROOT: /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf
```

I build the library using the make command and run into the following error

```
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/‌​ld: cannot find /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libc.so.6 inside /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/‌​ld: cannot find /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libc_nonshared.a inside /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf        
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/‌​ld: cannot find /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 inside /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf
```

But when I open the location `/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib` I can find all the three error files mentioned above ie `libc.so.6`, `libc_nonshared.a` and `ld-linux-armhf.so.3`

As per the suggestions of @jww, I'm shifting this to a new question since I'm having trouble linking. My results here are left for completeness.

Comment: As per your suggestion, I will make another question.

Comment: New question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31698241/linking-error-when-compiling-crypto-for-armhf

Comment: Where did you get the toolchain? Is it Ubuntu? Terry Guo and ARM? Or someone else's?

Comment: i installed the toolchain using
`apt-get install arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++`

Comment: We recently added a message to [direct you to the next step after running `setenv-*.sh`](http://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/commit/a6090c64edfc51d9d573398d4b266b2718d09546). I'm kicking myself in my ass-end because I should have realized it was needed a long time ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I install the libcryptopp libraries of the armhf architecture on my x64 based PC so I can cross compile? or is there any other way to resolve this issue.

Checkout [ARM Embedded (Command Line)](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/ARM_Embedded_%28Command_Line%29) on the Crypto++ wiki.

<strike>Note: that wiki page is a bit dated. You can now use [`GNUmakefile-cross`](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/GNUmakefile-cross). I have not updated the page to reflect recent changes like [`GNUmakefile-cross`](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/GNUmakefile-cross).</strike>

[`GNUmakefile-cross`](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/GNUmakefile-cross) is a special purpose built for cross-compiling on Android, iOS, Windows Phone, ARM Embedded, and bare metal (I doubt anyone would do the later, but I tested it as a platform). You will still need to run the `setenv-embedded.sh` script.

To fetch the latest sources from GitHub:

```
git clone https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp.git cryptopp-armhf
```

The GitHub sources are quite active at the moment. We are preparing for a Crypto++ 5.6.3 release. 5.6.3 will include 
[`GNUmakefile-cross`](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/GNUmakefile-cross).

---

The complete instructions will look something like (assuming you have the tools installed):

```sh
git clone https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp.git cryptopp-armhf
cd cryptopp-armhf

# Note the leading dot!!!
. ./setenv-embedded.sh
# The command above must execute successfully
# It cannot display a message like "**CXX is not valid**"

# Build it
make -f GNUmakefile-cross static dynamic cryptest.exe

# Check it
$ find . -name cryptest.exe
./cryptest.exe
$ /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-readelf -h ./cryptest.exe | grep -i 'class\|machine' 
  Class:                             ELF32
  Machine:
```

<strike>Because the GitHub sources are quite active at the moment, I've already added all the other files from `Crypto++-Mobile.zip` and `Setenv-embedded.sh.zip` to the official Crypto++ sources. You only need to get `setenv-embedded.sh` out of the `Setenv-embedded.sh.zip`.</strike>

Comment: had to run the command as root
`git clone https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp.git cryptopp-armhf`

Comment: *"had to run the command as root ..."* - that's odd. Usually that's a userland command.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [jww's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31665198/60075), I wanted to add some further notes. (These notes are relevant for version 5.6.3 released 20-Nov-2015.)

It may be necessary to edit the `config.h` file to change some options. See [Config.h on the Crypto++ wiki](https://cryptopp.com/wiki/Config.h). In particular:

- `CRYPTOPP_NO_UNALIGNED_DATA_ACCESS` may need to be defined so that the code operates properly on systems that can't do unaligned data read/writes (e.g. ARM).
- `CRYPTOPP_INIT_PRIORITY` and `CRYPTOPP_USER_PRIORITY` may need to be defined. See [Static Initialization Order Fiasco - Crypto++ Wiki](https://cryptopp.com/wiki/Static_Initialization_Order_Fiasco) for details.
- `CRYPTOPP_MAINTAIN_BACKWARDS_COMPATIBILITY_562` may need to be defined or undefined, depending on whether the project using it is using older API features or not.

After building the library, it is very much worth running the test program `cryptest.exe v` on the target system, to check if the library has been built okay for that system. For example, by doing this, I discovered that the library doesn't work properly on the ARM-based BeagleBone Black unless I define `CRYPTOPP_NO_UNALIGNED_DATA_ACCESS` in `config.h` (it freezes indefinitely on the test step `Testing MessageDigest algorithm SHA-384.`).

Comment: Good points Craig. `CRYPTOPP_MAINTAIN_BACKWARDS_COMPATIBILITY_562` will go away as soon as we release Crypto++ 5.7. We are tracking it at [Issue 70: Remove MAINTAIN_BACKWARDS_COMPATIBILITY_562](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/issues/70). We needed to leave it in place in an attempt to stay ABI compatible.

Comment: *"I discovered that the library doesn't work properly on the ARM-based BeagleBone Black..."* - Here's the bug reports for the issue: [Issue 45: Attempt to support GCC's -fdevirtualize](http://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/issues/45) and [Issue 47: Hang in SHA with Debian Sid, GCC 5.2 and Core2 Duo hardware](http://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/issues/47). Issue 47 was cleared with Issue 45.