# Linking error when compiling Crypto++ for ARMHF

Tags: c++, linker, arm, embedded, crypto++

I'm trying to compile the crypto++ library to run for the armhf architecture. I'm following the method provided in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31665198/3079474). I tweaked the `setenv-embed.sh` to match my system's configuration. The output of running `. ./setenv-embed.sh` is

```
CPP: /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-cpp 
CXX: /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
AR: /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-ar
LD: /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld
RANLIB: /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-ranlib-4.8

ARM_EMBEDDED_TOOLCHAIN: /usr/bin
ARM_EMBEDDED_CXX_HEADERS: /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/4.8.2
ARM_EMBEDDED_FLAGS: -march=armv7-a mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=neon -I/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/4.8.2 -I/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/4.8.2/arm-linux-gnueabihf 
ARM_EMBEDDED_SYSROOT: /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf
```

which indicates that the correct compilers have been found. However, when I build the library using `make` I run into the following error

```
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/‌​ld: cannot find /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libc.so.6 inside /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/‌​ld: cannot find /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libc_nonshared.a inside /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf        
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/‌​ld: cannot find /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 inside /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf
```

But when I open the location `/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib` I can find all the three error files mentioned above ie `libc.so.6`, `libc_nonshared.a` and `ld-linux-armhf.so.3`

I'm trying to compile the library for Beaglebone, if that helps.

**Update 1:**

The results of running `make -f GNUmakefile-cross system` after doing a fresh `git pull`

```
hassan@hassan-Inspiron-7537:~/cryptopp-armhf$ make -f GNUmakefile-cross system
CXX: /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
CXXFLAGS: -DNDEBUG -g2 -Os -Wall -Wextra -DCRYPTOPP_DISABLE_ASM -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=neon -mthumb -I/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/4.8.2 -I/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/4.8.2/arm-linux-gnueabihf --sysroot=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf -Wno-type-limits -Wno-unknown-pragmas
LDLIBS: 
GCC_COMPILER: 1
CLANG_COMPILER: 0
INTEL_COMPILER: 0
UNALIGNED_ACCESS: 
UNAME: Linux hassan-Inspiron-7537 3.13.0-35-generic #62-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 15 01:58:42 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
MACHINE: 
SYSTEM: 
RELEASE: 
make: Nothing to be done for `system'.
```

Comment: The embedded tag will get the question on the right expert's radar. There are some very sharp folks who follow the embedded tag. Sorry I could not be of assistance.

Comment: "/usr/bin/ ..." "cannot find /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ ..." PATH missmatch?

Comment: I don't think so. 
The first `usr/bin/` are pointing to the paths of the compiler executables.
The odd thing is that the files it claims to not find exist in the directory

Comment: That normally occurs because of a mismatch in address width which causes the linker to reject them. Are you trying to use ARMv8 64-bit libraries for an ARMv7 32-bit compile? Try running objdump on the libraries and it will tell you what they are compiled for.

Comment: @user3079474 - *"when I library using `make`..."* This just caught my eye... Are you running just `make`; or are you running `make -f GNUmakefile-cross`?

Comment: The latter. I run make - f GNUmakefile-cross

Comment: @user3079474 - Please show us the linker invocation so we can see the `--sysroot` setting. And what is the result of `find /usr/lib/gcc-cross -name libc.so.6`? And did you sya this was a [BeagleBoard](http://beagleboard.org/)? I just bought one to try and help with the issue.

Comment: @user3079474: *"Please show us the linker invocation..."* - Even better: do a `git pull`, and then `make -f GNUmakefile-cross system` (I just added the target). Then add the results to your question.

Comment: @jww i just noticed. its a beaglebone (not board). You may use a beaglebone black to test out the issue as well. Both beaglebone (BB) and beaglebone black (BBB) are fairly compatible plus BBB is the cheaper and the latest version

Answer (score 2):

The problem is simple. It is in the `--sysroot` option. The value of this option is `/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/` and it is used by the linker and the resulting library folder becomes
`/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/`

I removed the `--sysroot` option from line 68 in the file GNUmakefile-cross and everything compiled and linked OK.

However, I couldn't run the example on my BeagleBone Black because of mismatch of some shared libraries versions. But this wasn't a real problem for me, because in my application I link crypto++ statically, not dynamically.

Comment: *... I couldn't run the example on my BeagleBone Black..."* - you can SSH into the device and build on the device. I have a BBB, and I do the same for testing the library. *"...mismatch of some shared libraries versions"* - Yeah, I could see where a Ubuntu cross-compiler and a Texas Instruments (TI) image would do that. Maybe you need to use a TI cross-compiler. To enjoy room for development (4GB emmc don't have a lot of space), you should use a console image from, say, [Beagleboard:BeagleBoneBlack Debian](http://elinux.org/Beagleboard:BeagleBoneBlack_Debian)

Comment: @jww: I didn't investigate too much the mismatch of the versions of the shared libraries because it was not related to my application.

Comment: @jww (continued from my previous comment): For cross-development of BeagleBone applications I use Eclipse and desktop Ubuntu (running in a Virtual Box). It works very well with crypto++. Well, I had to spend some time figuring out how to configure Eclipse for remote debugging of BeagleBone applications.

Comment: Do you know if the include directory is messed up, too? I.e., is it ***`$SYSROOT/include`***, or is it ***`$SYSROOT/$SYSROOT/include`*** (like ***`$SYSROOT/$SYSROOT/lib`*** as you've shown above)?

Comment: The include directory is used by the compiler. I could compile the example code with the --sysroot option present. The library directory is used by the linker. It seems to me that the compiler doesn't use the --sysroot and linker does use it. And it seems to me that the linker prefixes the library directory with the sysroot directory. The result is $SYSROOT/$LIBDIR. It is the same as $SYSROOT/$SYSROOT/lib, but I think that $SYSROOT/$LIBDIR is a better interpretation. However, I am neither a Linux expert, nor gcc expert - I just use them sometimes. It might be a bug in the linker.

Comment: Also, in my particular case I didn't need sysroot at all. This is why I could simply remove it.

Comment: @jww: I noticed that there are two files in the /usr/bin/ directory which look like linker configuration files: arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld.bfd and arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld.gold. Unfortunately, they are not text files and I cannot view them. Maybe the linker gets the library directory from one of those files. And when the --sysroot option is specified, the library directory gets prefixed by the value of sysroot. But this is only an assumption - I am not a gcc expert and it is a mystery for me why the linker works when the --sysroot option is not specified and doesn't work when it is specified.

Comment: There are two linker options for the library path: -L and --library-path. None of them is used in setenv-embedded.sh or GNUmakefile-cross. It is not clear for me from where the linker gets the library path, maybe it gets it from some configuration file. Also, the linker documentation says that in some cases the library path will be prefixed by the value of --sysroot, if it is present, but it is not too clear how this works. So, my opinion is to use -L instead of --sysroot. However, when --sysroot is not present somehow the linker works properly even without the -L option.

Comment: @jww: Can you explain why GNUmakefile-cross uses --sysroot? In the case of GNUmakefile-cross it is not clear to me which tool is supposed to use the value of --sysroot and why.

Comment: `--sysroot` is used to set directories. Also see [GCC Directory Options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html). Its especially helpful in cross-compiles, and its the way to do things. The compiler driver uses `--sysroot`, and based on it, the driver knows what directories to pass to the preprocessor, the compiler proper, collect and the linker.

Comment: Can you try with `--sysroot` and `--no-sysroot-suffix`? `--sysroot` is existing, but you will need to add `--no-sysroot-suffix` to test it.

Comment: @jww: Didn't work. The --no-sysroot-suffix made no difference.

Comment: I found some good --sysroot explanation here: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0493i/BABDFCGG.html

Answer (score 0):

Based on Crosswalking's research I think I can explain *what* is going on. I don't think I agree with the assessment *"The problem is simple. It is in the `--sysroot` option"* since the Crypto++ environment script and makefile are doing things as expected.

I think Crosswalking's answer could be *how* to work around it; but see open questions below. The following is from [Crypto++ Issue 134: setenv-embedded.sh and GNUmakefile-cross](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/issues/134):

> I think this another distro problem, similar to [g++-arm-linux-gnueabi
>   cannot compile a C++ program with
>   --sysroot](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-defaults-armel-cross/+bug/1375071).
>   It might be a Ubuntu problem or a Debian problem if it is coming from
>   upstream.
>
> When cross-compiling, we expect the following (using ARMHF):
>
> - `SYSROOT` is `/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf`
> - `INCLUDEDIR` is `/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include`
> - `LIBDIR` is `/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib`
> - `BINDIR` is `/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin`
>
> How `LIBDIR` morphed into into
>   `/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/` (i.e.,
>   `$SYSROOT/$SYSROOT/lib`) is a mystery. But in all fairness, building
>   GCC is not a trivial task.
>
> You should probably file a bug report with Debian or Ubuntu (or
>   whomever provides the toolchain).

---

The open question for me is, since *`$SYSROOT/lib`* is messed up, then is *`$SYSROOT/include`* messed up, too?

If the include directory is also messed up, then the cross compile is using the host's include files, and not the target include files. That will create hard to diagnose problems later.

If both *`$SYSROOT/include`* and *`$SYSROOT/lib`* are messed up, then its not enough to simply remove *`--sysroot`*. Effectively, this is what has to be done:

```
# Exported by setenv-embedded
export=ARM_EMBEDDED_SYSROOT=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf

# Used by the makefile
-I $ARM_EMBEDDED_SYSROOT/$ARM_EMBEDDED_SYSROOT/include
-L $ARM_EMBEDDED_SYSROOT/$ARM_EMBEDDED_SYSROOT/lib
```

Which means we should be able to do the following:

```
# Exported by setenv-embedded
export=ARM_EMBEDDED_SYSROOT=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf

# Used by the makefile
--sysroot="$ARM_EMBEDDED_SYSROOT"
```

---

Finally, this looks a lot like Ubuntu's [Bug 1375071: g++-arm-linux-gnueabi cannot compile a C++ program with --sysroot](http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-defaults-armel-cross/+bug/1375071). The bug report specifically calls out ***... the built-in paths use an extra "/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi"***.

> We need the paths:
>
> A) /usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.7.3
>    B)
>   /usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.7.3/arm-linux-gnueabi
>
> But the built-in paths tries to use:
>
> C) /usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.7.3
>   D)
>   /usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.7.3/arm-linux-gnueabi/sf
>   E)
>   /usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.7.3/backward
>
> Notice the built-in paths use an extra "/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi"